# Simple question about Darlington BJT

Tags: transistors, resistance, pnp, darlington

I have this circuit for a pasive balancing battery cell with 2 PNP Darlington transistors with switching role.

When I close the circuit with the optocoupler the transistors are open.
R7 and R1 are power resistors. They have 0.68ohms.

What is the main role of the 10k resistor R14?

[image]

Comment: A mix of non-std symbols makes it harder to read the schematic. What did you expect this circuit to do? The input controls are undefined to enable this active load makes it vague with two gnd symbols GND and +GND

Comment: I think that's Autodesk Eagle @Tony.  It likes to leave alignment marks on everything.

Answer (score 0):

When the switch is open the 10K resistor should pull the bases of the two transistors high and thereby stop them from conducting.

However, the LED and R6 may prevent that from working properly.

A better question is "what is the role of R5"?

Comment: And another question is why bother using/showing the opto with shorted inputs and outputs with a mechanical switch over it. I suspect the control is R5 and feedback is Control_C1

Answer (score 0):

It’s an ugly schematic.

It ought t[o look more like this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCAMB00IQVnHCCIHZMGZoA4IA2AThMxCWksuqQFMBaMMAKABYFKJ8R1ekRav3AwAOgGdmk9rDBlyYJPkI4cRJCUlocEJBDyccJMNAiQck09EkATegDMAhgFcANgBdxUsJJywSIkx2dnwkdkx8dmIcfElGHT0kMHZkoQQiMGCrBDtHV08QZg4ufV4ITkoSKArqMG9pCVl5MkwlFQN1TW1YAz0DaCMok1SiHJsJe2d3LwnG-0Dg0PDI0KXMeMSkZNSlEmNt6A2JazzpwuKAJxB2InZwIRu7vgIYVERWa8FhCspHwzecCI%20E%20VSgAM0NUEgNgwNBt3utW45Uq1Ai8OeIjKL14aMwrAA7iAcPo%20JVdMJKhBCX86tVaQ86jS7nVHizwJA%20DSEYyGWBHtAad9eZDeYKAG4gdkQX7s-nUBU3NG9QEwWBIEoUEk1SrsflkplE6Wy8mDGBC%20ky%206i%20XgVgAD2JVD4PCdFAM9XuKTtju1fECTpI-qDXsRDpuWBdKHYOERrtDN3D0XKJF4MZQeE94HuOCF-zNooBgqJhbN7KLFqgtrlAu5mNePKRxZuoT4mCgIV4FZL%20funeJZub5bL5PUXKJjd1raR1IA5sT0G3wYui%20brhSl06au23jLBQAlBeU4Q7pH1KtcCDqvjXhXq1jz8tj8vAt65x0x%20pgKI3ZLgfAUF6RAgPuGpAA) then the function of R5 is obvious.

[image]

Although this is an “XY” question , I’ll give you some more hints.
[image]

The hFE won’t be 10k on the transistors. FETs would be better as when Vce(sat) @ Ic/Ib=100 for Darlingtons.  and you won’t get 50mA with 220 ohm LED bias from 5V into each base or 100mA output from this opto unless you use another inverting driver for these PNP’s .

THe PNP’s both need heat sinks and the resistors need to be elevated high off the PCB for better convection cooling if you plan on 5A per BJT at CC on Li Ion.

The LED can be ON to indicate charging and OFF to indicate bypass balancing as shown above.

[The input logic may be reversed with Anode high and Low side drive.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCAMB00IQVnHCCIHZMGZoA4IA2AThMxCWksuqQFMBaMMAKABYFKJ8R1ekRav3AwAOgGdmk9rDBlyYJPkI4cRJCUlocEJBDyccJMNAiQck09EkATegDMAhgFcANgBdxUsJJywSIkx2dnwkdkx8dmIcfElGHT0kMHZkoQQiMGCrBDtHV08QZg4ufV4ITkoSKArqMG9pCVl5MkwlFQN1TW1YAz0DaCMok1SiHJsJe2d3LwnG-0Dg0PDI0KXMeMSkZNSlEmNt6A2JazzpwuKAJxB2InZwIRu7vgIYVERWa8FhCspHwzecCI%20E%20VSgAM0NUEgNgwNBt3utW45Uq1Ai8OeIjKL14aMwrAA7iAcPo%20JVdMJKhBCX86tVaQ86jS7nVHizwJA%20DSEYyGWBHtAad9eZDeYKAG4gdkQX7s-nUBU3NG9QEwWBIEoUEk1SrsflkplE6Wy8mDGBC%20ky%206i%20XgVgAD2JVD4PCdFAM9XuKTtju1fECTpI-qDXsRDpuWBdKHYOERrtDN3D0XKJF4MZQeE94HuOCF-zNooBgqJhbN7KLFqgtrlAu5mNePKRxZuoT4mCgIV4FZL%20funeJZub5bL5PUXKJjd1raR1IA5sT0G3wYui%20brhSl06au23jLBQAlBeU4Q7pH1KtcCDqvjXhXq1jz8tj8vAt65x0x%20pgKI3ZLgfAUF6RAgPuGpAA)